# How do I add ADTS header when reading m4a raw data from iPod library?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, libvlc

**Objective**

Reading `m4a` file bought from iTunes Store via `AVAssetReader`.
Stream via `HTTP` and consumed by `MobileVLCKit`.

**What I've tried**

As far as I know, `AVAssetReader` only generates audio raw data, so I guess I should add [ADTS](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS) header in front of every sample.

```
NSError *error = nil;
AVAssetReader* reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:&error];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return -1;
}

AVAssetTrack* track = [asset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *readerOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:track
                                                                                        outputSettings:nil];
[reader addOutput:readerOutput];
    [reader startReading];
    while (reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading){
        AVAssetReaderTrackOutput * trackOutput = (AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *)[reader.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef;
        @synchronized(self) {
            sampleBufferRef = [trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
        }
        CMItemCount = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBufferRef);
        ...
    }
```

So, my question is, how do I loop every sample and add ADTS header?

Comment: What do you want from the m4a file? LPCM samples or AAC packets?

Comment: I want MobileVLCKit can recognize the codec, generate LPCM needs extra decoding effort and time, so I prefer AAC packet if possible.

Comment: AVFoundation can decide to LPCM using hardware... Why use MobileVLCKit at all?

Comment: This is a part of my implementation of UPnP Digital Media Server (DMS), I have to make sure it can be played by other players, including my local one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need `trackOutput`, it's the same as `readerOutput` that you already have.

**UPDATE**
My mistake, you're absolutely right. I thought the usual `0xFFF` sync words *were* part of AAC, instead they're ADTS headers. So you must add an ADTS header to each of your AAC packets to stream them as ADTS or "aac". I think you have two choices:

1. Use `AudioFileInitializeWithCallbacks` + `kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType` to get the `AudioFile` API to add the headers for you. You write AAC packets to the `AudioFileID` and it will call your write callback from where you can stream AAC in ADTS.
2. Add the headers to the packets yourself. They're only 7 fiddly bytes (9 with checksums, but who uses them?). Some readable implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17357008/22147) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18970406/22147)

Either way you need to call either  `CMSampleBufferGetAudioStreamPacketDescriptions` or `CMSampleBufferCallBlockForEachSample` to get the individual AAC packets from a `CMSampleBufferRef`.

Comment: I have tried streaming raw aac data to VLC, but it doesn't work. According to http://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=Understanding_AAC ,  it seems I have to use ADTS or ADIF header to package AAC data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although I achieved my goal yesterday in another way(http://stackoverflow.com/a/11600811/1060971), but the api you post here make me write cleaner code.